# Wordpress store get_posts data in variables

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

i have this code

```
global $post;
    $size = array(75,75);
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'category' => 'Allgemein' );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );



    foreach( $myposts as $post ) {  setup_postdata($post); 

        echo the_title();
        echo "<br>";
        echo the_excerpt();
        echo "<br>";
        echo the_permalink(); 
        echo "<br>";
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, $size);
        echo "<br>";


     };
```

how can i save the data for each post in different variables like this ?:

```
 $post9_title = $latesposts[8]->the_title();
```

Thanks in advance, i appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make counter and pull values for each post in array.

```
$posts_info = array();
$counter = 0;

foreach( $myposts as $post ) {  setup_postdata($post); 

    $posts_info[$counter]['title'] = get_the_title($post->ID);
    $posts_info[$counter]['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt($post->ID);
    $posts_info[$counter]['link'] = get_the_permalink($post->ID);
    $posts_info[$counter]['thumb'] = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $size);

    $counter++;
};
```

Comment: how can i access the title of the first post ? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Store them in an array instead so that you can use it broadly.

```
$store_post_data = array();
foreach( $myposts as $post ) {  setup_postdata($post); 
        $store_post_data[get_the_ID()]['title'] = get_the_title();
        $store_post_data[get_the_ID()]['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt();
        $store_post_data[get_the_ID()]['permalink'] = get_permalink();
        $store_post_data[get_the_ID()]['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $size);
};
```

Then print the array outside the loop.

```
print_r($store_post_data);
```